# Checking API calls in chrome network tab with nuxt

Tags: vue.js, fetch, google-chrome-devtools, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am new to Nuxt and I want to see my API calls in my network tab. I understand Nuxt is SSR and it doesn't show APIs in its `fetch()` hook in network tab. I searched online quite a bit but couldn't find a way to examine my API calls in network tab. So I was wondering if there is a way to see your API calls on `fetch()` hook, in network tab to examine them with Nuxt?

Comment: What happens if you navigate to another page requires API call? Still not shown?